Compiling Quarto with Shinylive PandocError
I want to render a html using quarto, following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6y2FnAugP8E
Within the quarto document I have a basic shinylive application
However, rendering raises the error
quarto preview ".../r-shinylive-demo/R-shinylive-demo.qmd" --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
pandoc 
  to: html
  output-file: R-shinylive-demo.html
  standalone: true
  section-divs: true
  html-math-method: mathjax
  wrap: none
  default-image-extension: png
  
metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  title: Our first r-shinylive Quarto document!
  
(E) Error running 'Rscript' command. Perhaps you need to install / update the 'shinylive' R package?
 Error:
 PandocError {}
Error running filter C:/Users/BADER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:
...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:40: Error running 'Rscript' command. Perhaps you need to install / update the 'shinylive' R package?

stack traceback:
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:40: in global 'throw_quarto_error'
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:86: in global 'callRShinylive'
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:113: in global 'callShinylive'
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:286: in global 'ensureBaseSetup'
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:315: in global 'ensureLanguageSetup'
        ...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:424: in function <...live-demo\_extensions\quarto-ext\shinylive\shinylive.lua:408>
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in method 'walk'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:557: in local 'checked_walk'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:609: in function 'run_emulated_filter'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1334: in local 'callback'
        [string "..."]:1888: in field 'withScriptFile'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1350: in upvalue 'run_emulated_filter_chain'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1388: in function <...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1385>
stack traceback:
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:557: in local 'checked_walk'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:609: in function 'run_emulated_filter'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1334: in local 'callback'
        [string "..."]:1888: in field 'withScriptFile'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1350: in upvalue 'run_emulated_filter_chain'
        ...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1388: in function <...DER/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/main.lua:1385>

I tried reinstalling pandoc and shinylive. Both dictionaries also in PATH.
I don't know how to solve the issue PandocError{}
Can someone help me please?
The .qmd document

    ---
    title: "Our first r-shinylive Quarto document!"
    filters:
      - shinylive
    format: 
        html
    ---
    
    ```{shinylive-r}
    #| standalone: true
    #| viewerHeight: 600
    library(shiny)
    library(bslib)
    
    # Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
    ui <- page_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(open = "open",
        numericInput("n", "Sample count", 100),
        checkboxInput("pause", "Pause", FALSE),
      ),
      plotOutput("plot", width=1100)
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      data <- reactive({
        input$resample
        if (!isTRUE(input$pause)) {
          invalidateLater(1000)
        }
        rnorm(input$n)
      })
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        hist(data(),
          breaks = 40,
          xlim = c(-2, 2),
          ylim = c(0, 1),
          lty = "blank",
          xlab = "value",
          freq = FALSE,
          main = ""
        )
        
        x <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, length.out = 500)
        y <- dnorm(x)
        lines(x, y, lwd=1.5)
        
        lwd <- 5
        abline(v=0, col="red", lwd=lwd, lty=2)
        abline(v=mean(data()), col="blue", lwd=lwd, lty=1)
    
        legend(legend = c("Normal", "Mean", "Sample mean"),
          col = c("black", "red", "blue"),
          lty = c(1, 2, 1),
          lwd = c(1, lwd, lwd),
          x = 1,
          y = 0.9
        )
      }, res=140)
    }
    
    # Create Shiny app ----
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
    ```



quarto check could not identify a installed version of R.
So I added ...R\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.4.1\bin to PATH.
Now it is working
